# OS X Lion machines will continually query Active Directory 2008 for every user in the directory

Tags: active-directory, osx-lion

We are having a problem where our OS X Lion machines will continually query Active Directory 2008 for every user in the directory until a user logs into the machine. When a user logs into the machine, the continuous, expensive queries stop. The problem queries start again as soon as the user logs out. This is a significant load on the domain controllers (DCs) and triggers Field Engineering 5 events on the DCs. We do not use OS X Server Lion.

Comment: I would look at two things. 1. Look carefully at the ldap query and filters on the client side. Experiment. 2. See if any job is running on the OS X systems that requires user information. Try to track the LDAP query down to the requesting service.

Comment: Can you provide the full Event entry? All the query details

Comment: Recomend closing as duplicate of this one that was closed: http://serverfault.com/questions/417945/os-x-lion-and-active-directory-inefficient-queries

Comment: This question has the exact same problems as the previous one -- there isn't enough troubleshooting information for us to offer any advice. I won't mod-hammer this closed, but I doubt you're going to get any kind of good answers without more detail (like what [kmarsh is asking for in their comment](http://serverfault.com/questions/466289/os-x-lion-machines-will-continually-query-active-directory-2008-for-every-user-i#comment553706_466289))